# How do you avoid strings being rendered by React with the quotation marks around them?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to store HTML snippets in Javascript strings, and then render them in react whenever a "view source" button is clicked.

This is an example of what the string looks like:

```
var testString = "&lang;!DOCTYPE HTML&rang;"
```

And within my React component's render function, it looks like:

```
return <pre>{testString}</pre>;
```

However this just spits out the string, without converting any of the escape characters. When I inspect the HTML, the string is being inserted within the HTML with the quotation marks around it. I tried using:

```
var testString = String(/&lang;!DOCTYPE HTML&rang;/).substring(1).slice(0,-1);
```

to remove the quotations from the string, but that didn't change anything. I've also tried placing it in `<p>`, `<div>`, and `<code>` tags without success. Any ideas as to why its doing this?

Also, if this is how the browser displays things within quotation marks, can I just display the HTML code on my webpage within quotation marks without using escape characters? i.e.

```
var testString = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
return <pre dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: testString }} />;
```